# Why does one drain strainer rust while the other does not?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, oxidation-state

About a month back, I acquired [drain strainers](https://images.app.goo.gl/BmoB7AHusJoTgkmj7) for my shower and kitchen sink.  The package I got included one of each, which I installed immediately.

Within two weeks, the shower strainer was showing spots of rust, and currently has several large holes where the wire mesh has disintegrated.  The kitchen strainer is perfectly fine (except for the cheese I haven't managed to clean off yet.

What could be causing the difference in rusting?  More importantly, what can I do to prevent the replacement shower strainer from rusting this quickly?

Comment: Some steel meshes are stainless steel, so they are rust resistant, and other steel meshes might be not stainless steel, to save a little money. You might try testing them with a magnet: some stainless steels are nonmagnetic or almost so, while ordinary steels are often ferromagnetic. If the magnet sticks to the shower drainer steel mesh, probably that drainer should be upgraded to a stainless steel mesh one. And take the magnet to the store to avoid non-stainless steel.

Comment: My guess would be that they are chrome plated steel . The one in the shower had thin or defective ,or damaged plating.

Comment: @blacksmith37 What you suggest is more likely than my comment, especially given that the two strainers were in the same purchased package. I guess “stainless steel” ain’t what it used to be!

Comment: Switch places, see what happens.

Comment: @IvanNeretin unfortunately, they're different sizes.